# Attempting to open report to specific record but it keeps showing all records - sort of?

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have a report with several sub-reports which are all extract data from the same table.  The only reason I made them sub-reports is for size constraints in using Access to create reports (21 inch issue).  I have form (`frmService`) that is loaded from another form (`frmWorkOrders` but that doesn't really matter I don't think) and it shows a single record in `tblServiceRecord`.  The form opens correctly, operates correctly to the same single record, however on `frmService` I have a control (button) that opens the report (`rptServiceRecord`) so we can print the record for our customers.  Anyway, the report ALWAYS brings up SOME of every record but not all parts of the multiple records.

I have several sub-reports (`srptFirstStage`, `srptSecondStage`, etc.) and the only two sub-reports that print every record are the two listed above.  All other sub-reports only print the associated record that I want it to print, even if there are multiple records in the database.  The weirdest part, and the part that's keeping me from solving this, is that all of the sub-reports were created equally.  The report itself has a filter (see code below) but none of the sub-reports have this filter in them.  I also have Filter On Load checked as `Yes`.  I also tried to use a query to create this report using the following SQL:

```
SELECT tblServiceRecord.*, tblWorkOrder.Task, [FName] & " " & [LName] AS FullName, "WD0" & [tblWorkOrder]![ID] AS WorkOrder
FROM tblServiceRecord INNER JOIN (tblCustomers RIGHT JOIN tblWorkOrder ON tblCustomers.ID = tblWorkOrder.CustomerID) ON tblServiceRecord.WorkOrderID = tblWorkOrder.ID
WHERE (((tblServiceRecord.WorkOrderID)=[Forms]![frmService]![txtWO]));
```

Bringing up the query in Datasheet view brings up the correct information and doesn't list multiple rows from the tables.  So I'm not entirely sure why the report does show multiple rows, even though the second rows `srptFirstStage` and `srptSecondStage` are showing are blank.

To open the report (`rptServiceRecord`) from the control I use:

```
Private Sub Command275_Click()
On Error GoTo Command275_Click_Err

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptServiceRecord", acViewPreview, , "[WorkOrderID] = Forms.[frmService].[txtWO]", acNormal


Command275_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command275_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command275_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in case `WorkOrderID` is a numeric field:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptServiceRecord", acViewPreview, , "[WorkOrderID] = " & Forms("frmService")("txtWO").Value, acNormal
```

Try this in case `WorkOrderID` is a string field:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptServiceRecord", acViewPreview, , "[WorkOrderID] = '" & Forms("frmService")("txtWO").Value & "'", acNormal
```

Comment: I edited my answer. The problem was the reference to the form and its control.

Comment: Maybe there is code in the report, disabling the filter?

Comment: The only thing I see in your report is that you didn't set `Link Master Fields` and `Link Child Fields` for the first two SubReport objects, namely `srptFirstStage` and `Child434`. I guess they should be set to `WorkOrderID` too, like the other SubReport objects, right? Without that, you have no correlation between them and the main report.

Comment: BINGO!  The linking of fields is what was wrong - THANKS!